# How to loop through files in a directory and then read them into a string variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I am trying to loop through a directory with a few .txt files in bash. I have very little experience with bash but I need to use it because I can run other commands once I get the contents of each file. I 
want to do this:

```
for file in <directory>; do
    read its contents
    do something with the contents
done
```

I found that to read a file you can do this with one file if I hard code the file name:

```
contents = $(<filename.txt)
```

and to loop through all files in a directory I am doing this:

```
for file in dir; do

done
```

I want to be able to loop through all files and read them with the file variable in the loop.
But inside the loop none of these work (I have tried combinations of these as well):

```
for file in dir; do
    contents = $(<$file)
done

for file in dir; do
     contents = $(<"$file")
done

for file in dir; do
     contents = $(<${file##*/})
done

for file in dir; do
     contents = $(<"${file##*/}")
done

for file in dir; do
     contents = $(<$(basename "$file"))
done

for file in dir; do
     filename = $(basename "$file")
     contents = $(<$filename)
done

for file in dir; do
     filename = "${file##*/}"
     contents = $(<$filename)
done
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: `for file in dir/*.txt; do echo "Showing $file ......"; contents=$(<"$file"); echo "$contents"; done`

Comment: I get command not found on 
     contents=$(<"$file")

Comment: I put this at the top #!/bin/bash otherwise how else would I make sure its bash and not sh. the file name is saved as a .sh

Comment: the files are there and I cd to that directory in the scrit before hand to make sure

Comment: Depending on what you're going to do with the contents, most likely this is not the best approach.

Comment: I think I have to use bash. There is another software called syntaxnet that parses text and it can be used by passing the text to a shell script so I think bash is the best option to open all the files and pass it to the syntaxnet script to run

Comment: @CostasVrahimis: Your shell-variable assignments all have whitespace around the `=`, which is not supported. Something like `contents = ...` (note the whitespace around `=`) will make the shell think you're executing a _command_ named `contents`, which fails.

Comment: @mklement0 that was definitely one of the issues thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
find <dir_path> -iname '*.txt' -exec cat {} + | your_parser
```

or just

```
cat /<dir_path>/*.txt | your_parser
```

Answer (score 2):

The larger question is whether you really need to read the contents of each file of interest into a shell variable, but to achieve just that, **the primary problem with your attempts was that you had *whitespace around the `=` sign* in your variable assignments**, which isn't supported.

Something like `contents = ...` (note the whitespace around `=`) will make the shell think you're executing a *command* named `contents`, which fails.

Thus, with that problem fixed and double-quoting of variables added for robustness, the following should work:

```
dir='.' # sample target dir

for file in "$dir"/*.txt; do
    contents=$(<"$file")  # read contents of file $file
    # ... work with "$contents"
done
```

Comment: I did realize this eventually late yesterday but thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below, using `process substitution <()`

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    # Your other actions on the files go here. The `-print0` option in
    # find command helps identify all zip files even with special characters
    # in them.
    # The bash variable "$file" holds the zip file name which you an use in

    printf "%s\n%s\n" "Contents of $file:-" "$(<file)"

done < <(find directory/ -name "*.txt" -type f -print0)
```

Comment: That's a robust solution, but it traverses the entire _subtree_ of the specified dir., whereas the OP's own attempts only focus on the `*.txt` files _directly_ contained in the target dir.

Comment: @mklement0: Thanks for the keen observation, perhaps a `-maxdepth 1` option in `find` command should fix it?

Comment: Yes, that would fix it, but, truthfully, in this simple case `for file in directory/*.txt; do ...` is the simpler and more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

For example's sake, we'll assume file1.txt contains "texta", file2.txt contains "text b", and file3.txt contains "textc". The text in file2.txt contains a space.

--

If the files are single-line files, or you otherwise don't need to work on each line individually, then your for loop is pretty much complete.

```
for file in dir/*; do
    contents="$contents $(<"$file")"
done
```

However, this makes a single line, with each file entry split by spaces. Depending on how the variable is used later, this might cause issues. Spaces from within the files and spaces surrounding each entry are indiscriminate

```
#Value of $contents:
texta text b textc
```

You can instead split each file text in a new line by using;

```
contents="$contents\n$(<"$file")"

#Value of $contents:
texta
text b
textc
```

But the same issue would happen if your text files contain multiple lines themselves.

You could also split each file's text into a seperate index in an array.

```
contents+=("$(<"$file")")
```

With an array, each entry can be referenced with ${contents[$i]}, where $i is the index number.

```
#Value of ${contents[0]}
texta
#Value of ${contents[1]}
text b
#Value of ${contents[2]}
textc
#Value of $(contents[*]} is all indexes. Listed values are automatically separated by a space.
texta text b textc
```

You can, of course, also do no separation,

```
contents="$contents$(<"$file")"

#Value of $contents:
textatext btextc
```

--

That all being said, if you need to split the files by line, with each line of each file seperated, you can do this with an imbedded while loop.

```
for file in dir; do
    while read line; do
        contents="$contents $(<"$line")"
    done <$file
done
```

This runs the while loop once per file found in the for loop. Again, the variable assignment line can be replaced with any of the other methods as needed.

Comment: I don't think the OP is looking to accumulate the content of _multiple_ files in a variable.